# DatePickerTextBox GotFocus event

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

How do I catch the `GotFocus` event from a `DatePickerTextBox` the `DatePicker` and `DatePickerTextBox` `GotFocus` and `GotKeyboardFocus` events does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

`GotFocus` event is internally handled by `DatePicker`. It by default changes `e.Handled = true` for all `GotFocus` `RoutedEvents` which are triggered by its textbox.

But `DatePicker.GotKeyboardFocus` event is not effected by this. You can still listen to that event.

In order to fire `GotFocus` event, you'll have to explicitly add an event handler to listen to this it and change `e.Handled` to `false`. i.e:

```
DatePicker1.AddHandler(DatePicker.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(DatePicker1_GotFocus), true);
void DatePicker1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

**Update:**

To open calendar upon focus use `PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
void DatePicker1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var dp = sender as DatePicker;
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        dp.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }      
}
```

Comment: The solution works well for the `GotFocus` but I'm trying to open the calendar
 `private void DpTb_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            dateP.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }`
and it thows an exeption `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot reopen a popup in the closed event handler.'`

Comment: You can achieve this by binding `PreviewKeyDown` Event of DatePicker.

Comment: I want to open the drop-down only when the `DatePicker` gets focused with a mouse click or tab key and not if I press a key when the textbox is focused

Comment: @user9285072 See my updated answer, you can handle key selection by `e.Key`